# Is it possible to display saved DatePicker inputs to another view

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker

I am trying to return DatePicker inputs which is saved to core data, from details view to another view. But nothing is being returned.

Where am I going wrong?

```
truct ProductCard: View {
@Environment (\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Task.name, ascending: true)])
    
   
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
            HStack{
                ForEach( Task, id: \.self){ Task in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ProductCardDetails(taskData: Task)
                    } label: {
                        HStack{
                            Text(task.self.taskTitle ?? "Error")
                                .font(.title3)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                            Spacer()
                            // this should be Date right?
                            Text(task.self.taskDate ?? "Error")
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }.padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// where the inputs will be put in

```
struct ProductCardDetails: View {

   let formatter: DateFormatter = {
       let formatter = DateFormatter()
       formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss"
       return formatter
   }()
   
   @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjContext
   @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
   var taskData: Task
   @State private var taskTitle: String = ""



   var body: some View {
       let binding = Binding<Date> {
           formatter.date(from: taskData.taskDate ?? "") ?? Date.now
       } set: { date, transaction in
           taskData.taskDate = formatter.string(from: date)
       }
       VStack{
           Form{
               Section(header: Text("Name the task"),
                       footer: Text("Footer of a section can contain extra information about this section")) {
                   TextField("Name your task", text: $taskTitle)
                       .disableAutocorrection(true)
               }
               Section(header: Text("When do you need to do this"),
                       footer: Text("")) {
                   DatePicker(selection: binding, in: ...Date()){
                                   Text("Pick time")
                               }
               }
               Button("Save and close"){
                   Task{
                       do{
                           try await managedObjContext.perform {
                               try managedObjContext.save()
                           }
                           dismiss.callAsFunction()
                       } catch{
                           print(error)
                       }
                   }
               }
           }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
       }
   }
```

}

\
Added an image of my new core data and hopefully the naming conventions are clearer
\
core data
[core data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIesi.png)
and
current errors
[Entering in product details error][3]
[Product card errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcfZt.png)

Comment: What is $dateandtime?

Comment: dateandtime Is where Date will be stored

Comment: Your latest edit will not compile but why aren’t you using the `dataSet` object instead?

Comment: Maybe that’s the cause? Could you assist in how to get it running as well explaining the solution to displaying date and time inputs to another view?